# GROUP BY query in Google Data Studio

Tags: mysql, looker-studio

I have a table that has several columns, including a column for the amount of tickets sold and a sales time column,
I want to know how many tickets were sold at any given hour.

For example

| time | tickets |
| --- | --- |
| 10:45 | 5 |
| 10:30 | 6 |
| 10:15 | 3 |
| 10:00 | 2 |
| 11:14 | 8 |
| 11:30 | 6 |

Here is the query I wrote-

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
SELECT hour(time) as hour, tickets  FROM Showtimes_View
group by hour(time)
order by hour
```

The query ran well on my MySQL,
[image]
The problem is that when I try to run it in Google Data Studio, I get an error.[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skip the  removing of full GROUP BY and use SUM as aggregation function

```
SELECT hour(time) as hour, SUM(tickets)  FROM Showtimes_View
group by hour(time)
order by hour
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this version on Standard BigQuery:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR from time) AS hour, SUM(tickets) AS num_tickets
FROM Showtimes_View
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

You remarked that `The query ran well on my MySQL`.  The query may have *ran*, but turning off `GROUP BY` strict mode to make a query run usually isn't best practice.